# SQL Server Compact Query Analyzer: How to change part of a string value in a table?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 database file which has `.sdf` extension. The database is created by a book cataloging application. The database has many tables, among them a table called `Book` which contains one row for each book in the database. The table has many columns among them a column called `FrontCover` which contains a string value which has 2 parts: `path part` and `file name part` of the image file for the front cover of a book, for example:

```
Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers\0596003978.jpg
```

In this example path part is:

```
'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers'
```

while file part is:

```
'0596003978.jpg'
```

Some books do not contain any value for the column `FrontCover` because the front cover is not available. For such books column `FrontCover` is empty. However if a book has a front cover image file then the string value has the same path part but different file part. For example for another book column `FrontCover` has this value:

```
'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers\1590596633.jpg'
```

As we can see the path part is the same as in the first example, namely:

```
'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers'
```

but the file part is different:

```
'1590596633.jpg'
```

**PROBLEM**:

I want to change the whole table `Book` so that string values of the column `FrontCover` are modified for every book in the table in such a way that file part is kept the same but the path part is changed from:

```
'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers'
```

to

```
'Books\AEM database\Covers'
```

The string value of the column `FrontCover` for the book in the first example would thus change from:

```
'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers\0596003978.jpg'
```

to

```
'Books\AEM database\Covers\0596003978.jpg'
```

File part is the same but the path part is changed. I want to change the whole `Book` table so that the file part of the string value for column `FrontCover` is kept the same but the path part is changed as specified above.

The book cataloging application which owns the `.sdf` database file is stupid and cannot do the job. Therefore I have installed a simple open source SQL viewing/editing application called SQL Compact Query Analyzer (http://sqlcequery.codeplex.com/). SQL Compact Query Analyzer can open `.sdf` database files and accepts SQL commands in order to modify the `.sdf` database file.

Can you please help me with the SQL commands which can do the job?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

best regards

Comment: Are all the paths under `Documents and Settings`?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE Book SET FrontCover = REPLACE(
    CAST(FrontCover AS NVARCHAR(300)),
    'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers',
    'Books\AEM database\Covers')
WHERE FrontCover like
    'Documents and Settings%'
```

Note: the where clause may not be necessary but it ensures that you only replace strings that start with 'Documents and Settings...'

Comment: After typing the proposed solution I get the following error code:
ErrorCode: -2147467259
[SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider] HResult: -2147217900, NativeError: 25922
ErrorMessage: The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = REPLACE ]

Comment: Ah yes, I assumed VARCHAR or NVARCHAR.  I edited my answer with `CAST(FrontCover AS NVARCHAR(300))`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Paul Brown is OK however it produced the following error code:

ErrorCode: -2147467259 [SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider] HResult: -2147217900, NativeError: 25922 ErrorMessage: The specified argument value for the function is not valid. [ Argument # = 1,Name of function(if known) = REPLACE ]

The reason for this is because the type of date for the column FrontCover is NTEXT (I forgot to specify that in my question) and function REPLACE does not allow NTEXT variable. So we have to covert FrontCover variable with the following command before passing it to REPLACE:

CAST(FrontCover AS NVARCHAR(100))

Therefore the answer to my question is:

UPDATE Book
SET FrontCover = REPLACE (CAST(FrontCover AS NVARCHAR(100)), 'Documents and Settings\Boson\My Documents\Books\Covers\', 'Books\AEM database\Covers\')